# C++ typedef, map, iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

Can anybody help me with an iterator problem? I'm having something like this:

```
class SomeClass{

public:
    //Constructor assigns to m_RefPtr a new t_Records
    //Destructor deletes m_RefPtr or decreases m_RefCnt
    //Copy Constructor assigns m_RefPtr to new obj, increases m_RefCnt
    bool Search(const string &);

private:
    //Some private variables

    struct t_Records{ //For reference counting

        int m_RefCnt; //Reference counter

        typedef vector<int> m_Vec;
        typedef map<string, m_Vec> m_Map;
        m_Map m_RecMap;

        t_Records(void){
            m_RefCnt = 1;
        }

    };

    t_Records * m_RefPtr;

};

//Searchs through the map of m_RefPtr, returns true if found
bool SomeClass::Search(const string & keyword){

    //How to create and use an iterator of m_Map???

    return true;

}
```

As how I mentioned, I'm having troubles with creating (defining) map iterator outside of the struct. The map is initalized and contains some records. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Like `m_Map::iterator`?!

Comment: There are multiple sources for potential issues in that design. What is concerning you at this time? The type? How to return the iterator? Lifetime extension of `m_RefPtr`? An iterator over the inner elements (i.e. over elements inside *all* the `std::vector<int>`?) --BTW, this looks like reimplementing `shared_ptr` all over again, you might want to consider using the standard smart pointer for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
// assuming m_RefPtr is properly initialized:
t_Records::m_Map::iterator it = m_RefPtr->m_RecMap.begin();
++it; // etc.
```

By the way, `m_Map` is a bad name for a type. By common convention, names prefixed with `m_` are used for data members.

Comment: It shouts:
solution.cpp:463:2: error: `m_Map` has not been declared
  m_Map::const_iterator itMap;

Comment: @marthin23 Hint: where is the `typedef`?

Comment: @marthin23 Sorry, didn't notice the nested struct definition. Fixed.

Comment: @jrok Thanks, that should be the missing piece, t_Reccords:: Damn!

Comment: And how it will look if I want to return the `t_Records::m_Map::iterator` from function (method)?
I'm trying `t_Records::m_Map::iterator SomeClass::SomeMethod(some param){ }`
and it shouts: it does not name a type

Comment: @marthin23 I'll let you figure that one out yourself. Hint: in what scope is `t_Records` declared?

Comment: @jrok Damn, again, again! Thanks a lot! SomeClass:: was the missing puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate like this

```
for (m_Map::iterator it = m_RecMap.begin(); it != m_RecMap.end(); ++it)
{
    // do stuff with *it
}
```

Or even easier

```
for (auto it = m_RecMap.begin(); it != m_RecMap.end(); ++it)
{
    // do stuff with *it
}
```